# Android Studio Debug

Tags: android-studio, debugging

i am testing my code but i have a problem, when i try to run the "Debug" process my cell phone get stock on [Waiting For Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqkil.png) screen and i have to use [Attach Debugger to Android Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lHEg.png) on Android Studio, it used to attach automatically but i have been changing my android studio configuration, if there any way to make it automatic again i tried i lot but i can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling `Tools-> Android -> Enable ADB Integration` off and on, I had this issue when switching to the beta 2 of Android Studio 3. This helped me solving the issue.